# Getting third triangle point coordinate in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How to get third point C coordinates in google maps javascript?

Knowing A, B points coordinates and distance D1, 
D2.

Triangle is right.

[image]

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543961/determine-third-point-of-triangle-when-two-points-and-all-sides-are-known) might help you

Comment: Give an example please.  Essentially it's just Pythagoras.  And figuring out degrees <-> kilometers conversion

Comment: It is not just Pytagoras triangle is on sphere.

Comment: Google Maps is a Mercator projection, which stretches a sphere to a rectangle.  As if the north pole (just a point) was 40Mm long, just like the equator

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Pythagoras. All you need to know are the points A and C, and you want to find the point due north from A, distance D2. How far B is from A hasn't got anything to do with it surely?  Unless you care about the acute angles of your triangle.

You need to use the `geometry` library when loading your map:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Then take point A, use the `computeOffset` method in the  [geometry.spherical namespace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#spherical) to work out the point C you get to by adding distance D2 to A.  With the 3rd parameter being the heading, i.e. degrees, in this case 0 for directly North.

```
var A = new google.maps.LatLng(41.4087436, 2.14716640000006);

var D2 = 1000; // metres

var C = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(A, D2, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to your question.  Just do what duncan sais.
Rather it extends the question, it adds extra questions, since your question is ambigious.

The whole reason that my countryman Gerard Mercator invented his projection method, is so that ships can use simple geometry.

Especially for angles.  Draw a straight line from origin to destination on his map, measure that angle, turn your ship to that angle, sail forward, keep that same angle (heading) on your compas and you will arive at you destination.

Notice: this is not the shortest path, it's the easiest path to travel on.

An axample: let's take three points on the straight borders of the USA, at the Canadian border.

A: (49.00, -117.00), B: (49.00, -97.00), C: (42.00, -117.00)

Vertical distance is easy.  360° = 40Mm.
=> A-C: distance = 40M * (49 - 42) / 360 = 777 km.

Horizontal, going due east or west: 360° = 40Mm * cosinus(lat) * 360
=> A-B: distance = (40M / 360) * (117 - 97) * cos(49°) = 1458 km.

Again, this is not the shortest distance between A and B, but it is the distance along the straight line on the map.  The shortest path A-B is a curved line that goes through Canada.
If your line is supposed to be a straight line on the map, this is the distance you are looking for.  The answer you'll get from Google Maps might be the shortest distance, thus not the straight line.

The triangle you want, doesn't exist.  Either all the lines are curved, or the angles are smaller.  The sum of the angles will be less than 180°.

So I'm not sure what sort of triangle you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Solved :)

So I have two known points A and B.

Distance D1 is not necessary.

```
// setting distance in metres between points A and C
var D2 = 100;

// calculate angle between points A and B
var angle = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(A, B);

// setting angle to 90 degrees
var newAngle = angle + 90; // OR angle - 90

// get new point C
var C =  google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(A, D2, newAngle);

// printing new point C coordinates
console.log(C.lat(), ' ', C.lng());
```

Comment: ah, I didn't realise the base of your triangle wasn't always on the same latitude.